# How to work with a local database file using Adobe HTML5 Extension?

Tags: javascript, sql, html, adobe-cc, extension-builder3

I am porting an Flash (ActionScript) extension to HTML5 extension. I am storing some data (table format) to a local sql database file (its just a file, no local server is setup). Other crucial information regarding this db file-

- I'm using the same db file for the InDesign/Photoshop/Illustrator.
- I can anytime take the backup of this file for future reference.

With the **actionscript** it was fine. I used `flash.data.SQLConnection`, `flash.data.SQLStatement` and was able to execute the queries and read/edit the file.

But how to do the same with the **HTML5 extension**? I tried using the `WebSQL` and `IndexedDB`, integration was fine but some major disadvantages-

1. The database files are created in the machine's "**Temp**" folder. - not preferred since it could be deleted anytime (as mentioned above, I can take backup of the database file)
2. The database files for ID/PS/IL are created in the **separate** folders - not matching my requirement (as mentioned above, I want to use the same db for all the applications)

   [image]

   [image]

So I think these web storage mechanisms are not of useful for the Adobe HTML5 Extensions at all!

What approach can I follow instead to achieve what I'm looking for, may be using the vbscript or something, I'm not sure!

I thought of using the simple file-handling (I know with js its not possible, but its supported in the extend script that I can use), but making the queries would be very complex, might effect the performance!

Am kinda stuck here! Any help will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/). It is a simple JSON storage lib. You can write a query plugin for it to fit your query needs or use the [gnarly lawnchair query plugin 0.6.1](http://brian.io/lawnchair/downloads/lawnchair-query-0.6.1.js).

This should fit your requirements except maybe performance which you'd have to test.